# How to calculate flow rate and direction in system with multiple blowers

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

I have an odour control system where foul air is being extracted from multiple sources and then pushed into a scrubber vessel. Normally, all my designs look something like this:

https://ibb.co/58YSdpc

With this arrangement, I'm able to maintain negative pressure at all sources which ensures that the foul air is being sucked into the treatment system, and that it doesn’t escape into the air through any openings.

However, I currently have a project where one of the sources is a sludge buffer tank that is being mixed through pressurised  air. The system looks like this: (Fans A/B are duty/standby arrangement with rating: 4650m3/hr @1500Pa)

https://ibb.co/bj04pBB

The compressor blows air into the tank from the bottom through the water, and the water level in the tank varies from 1 m to 4 m. This means the pressure in the headspace could range from 10,000 to 40,000 Pa (The way I did this is that  I subtracted the pressure of a water column 1m to 4m deep from the 50 kPa). I would like to know how the air flow rate directions and relative magnitudes  would be like in this system, and whether there will still be negative pressure in the sources. Thanks!

Comment: Why will the pressure in the headspace vary with depth of liquid - you show draw a diagram and show your calculations. Add to the original question - without links...

Comment: That's because the air is blown at the bottom of the tank. If the pressure of the air bubbles is 50 kPa at the bottom, then rising through the water in the tank should decrease its pressure by the pressure of the water column....I don't know how to post the diagrams without links.